# Bootstrap responsive div with order

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have 3 div. In PC, i want to show it same the picture. But when responsive, i  want to show with order 1 -> 2 -> 3. How can i do it, please me

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="portlet yellow-crusta box">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet yellow-crusta box">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="portlet blue-hoki box">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap classes properly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="portlet yellow-crusta box">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="portlet blue-hoki box">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="portlet yellow-crusta box">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```